# mingw 64 ships without make.exe?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I had an old version of mingw on my computer that compiles programs to 32 bit. Now I want to compile to 64 bit, so I downloaded the new mingw installer. It tried uninstalling and installing several times with different versions (x86_64 option each time), but some files appear to be missing each time, at least make.exe. There's no make.exe in any of the mingw subfolders, only mingw32-make.exe in

```
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1\mingw64\bin
```

I'm relatively new to c++, so maybe I'm overlooking something? https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Make/ mentions you can copy make to the bin folder, but where do I copy it from?

Comment: If you are not worried about make version issues, simply copy mingw32-make.exe  to make.exe.

Comment: Seems not to be compatible under NetBeans 8.2, I just and got the message "Not compatible, use make from MSYS instead". Sigh. This is why I prefer *nix.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

mingw32-make.exe is the one you want to use. It is the version of make shipped with MinGW-w64. A plain make.exe does not exist. Don’t get confused by the name. You use mingw32-make.exe no matter if you want to produce 32bit or 64bit binaries.

Comment: Adding this link for reference: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Make/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symbolic link make.exe target to mingw32-make.exe, this way you can run make instead of mingw32-make. I found Git Bash is very useful for running Linux like tools on Windows.