# Cross compile from Linux to Windows using mingw

Tags: linux, windows, cmake, mingw-w64, termcap

I'm trying to compile a application developed under Linux Debian for Windows 10 using the mingw compiler and cmake.

I configured a toolchain file according to the tutorial from [kitware](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/cross_compiling/Mingw) . This works great as long as I have no dependencies to libraries. Following the tutorial I have to install the libraries in the second path of this line:

```
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /usr/i586-mingw32msvc /home/<USER>/mingw-install )
```

I tried to download the library sources (e.g. for [Termcap](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/termcap.htm)) but I have not really an idea how to install the library under the path `/home/<USER>/mingw-install` using MinGW.

Could somebody give a example for Termcap what commands I have to invoke or a link to a tutorial?

Comment: So, which **exact** part of the installation is problematic for you? Do you know how to install given library under MinGW *in general* (without specific directory)? If you don't know that, then this should be your primary question. If you know how to install the library under MinGW, then [edit] the question post with the way you use to install. So we could tell you additional parameter or other setting, using which you could select the installation directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think the problem is that I don't know how to invoke the make file of a library with mingw. I read about mingw32-make, but I can't find something simillar for mingw64.

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753382/3440745) states that `mingw32-make` is suitable for 64-bit compilation too.

Comment: The answer you linked refers to the windows installation of mingw. I installed mingw on a debian machine via `apt install mingw-w64` - It seems that this package is shipped without mingw32-make and I can't figure out how to install mingw32-make via apt.

Comment: Oh, this is MinGW-on-Linux. Then just use **host** build system (e.g. `make` utility).