# CMake "c++ is unable to compile a simple test program." How do I fix this?

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, mingw32, cmake-language

It's 1:12 AM, and I'm tired and frustrated. I'm finally trying to learn cmake, but of course it's overwhelmingly complicated and a problem has show up that only I seemed to be affected with.

The error seems to be about the compiler (Which is g++) being unable to compile a simple test program, and because of that, cmake just won't bother to generate the Makefile.

Here's the CMakeList.txt I was using.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM make)

project(out VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
add_executable(out src/main.cpp)
```

The command I used
`cmake -S . -B build -G "MinGW Makefiles"`

And the error message in it's entirety

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/mingw64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/mingw64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: 'C:/Users/tyler/cpp_programs/learning_cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-46pogc'

    Run Build Command(s): C:/mingw64/bin/cmake.exe -E env VERBOSE=1 "" -f Makefile cmTC_0793c/fast
    The parameter is incorrect





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I can't believe that just making regular Makefiles is more simple than using Cmake. Really makes be wonder why people bothered using it. I'm just very frustrated you know? It feels like I'm working with a black box that always blindsides me with an issue I cannot comprehend.

I just want a solution. I'm using windows 10, I'm using x86_64-w64-mingw32 and NeoVim.

Comment: And if you remove CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM ? Cmake should detect automatically your Mingw installation when you have installed it correctly

Comment: Disclaimer, I not a cmake expert. For most people cmake works 'out of the box'. For whatever reason cmake has failed to understand your compiler, even though it knows where and what it is `Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed`

Comment: cmake isn't particularly complex (given what it is attempting to do). But you are stuck at the very first step (which is often the hardest). Sometimes this is because you are trying too hard, assuming that things are more complex than they are.

Comment: One thing I notice is the the generator that you are using "MinGW makefiles" is designed for use with mingw32-make but you are trying to use it with make. Could that be the issue? cmake generally auto detects this kind of thing, so I would remove anything where you are telling cmake to use particular tools or generators unless you find that cmake doesn't detect these things correctly **and you understand why it hasn't detected correctly**. Trying to patch some problem without understanding the nature of the problem rarely works.

Comment: You might want to uninstall everything and start again with more modern versions from msys64

Comment: In addition to what has been already said by other people if you are beginner in CMake I strongly recommend you to look at "Professional CMake: A Practical Guide" book written by Craig Scott(one of CMake maintainers). This book helped me a lot to understand what CMake is and how to use it correctly and I don't regret any penny spend on it. I regret only that I didn't know about this book earlier.

Comment: The error is about inability of CMake to find **Make utility** on your machine: the path to that utility should be inserted by CMake instead of empty string in `C:/mingw64/bin/cmake.exe -E env VERBOSE=1 "" -f Makefile cmTC_0793c/fast`. By setting `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM ` variable you tell CMake that the build utility could be run using the name `make`. But do you **actually** have `make.exe` executable on your machine? See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752721/mingw-64-ships-without-make-exe).

Comment: Yeah I do. I use a copied and renamed mingw32-make.exe, and I still have the original executable.